# swift3 wkwebview not working on certain devices

Tags: swift3, wkwebview

Any ideas why wkwebview would not work on certain devices? I am able to open the url in safari on the device but there is no network request when going through the app.

```
var webView: WKWebView!
 let myURL = URL(string: "https://mywebsitehere/" )
 let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
 webView.load(myRequest)
```

Is there some setting on a phone that could be blocking this? I have tried with 2 iPhone 6's running iOS 10 on the same network. One works and the other goes nowhere.

Comment: There is no specific setting for this, check your internet connection & permission on the device.

Comment: Internet is working fine because I am able to access the website in safari without a problem, what permissions would be on the device?

Comment: Mobile data & internet permission for specific application. you can check them in Settings.

Comment: nothing seems to change it there, strange, and I have deleted and reloaded the app. It does not give any errors either

Comment: implement delegate methods for `WKWebView` and then trace it.